# Как узнать, является ли объект из списка Components определенным объектом, например TPanel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как проверить является ли `Components[i]`, например, формы, панелью (т.е. объектом класса TPanel)?

Что-то типа:

```
  if (Form1.Components[i] as TPanel) then
```

Comment: Нужен оператор [**is**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator). А скобки не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Пробегаем все компоненты
for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
begin
  if (Components[I].ClassType = TComboBox) then // Если компонент является Комбобоксом
  begin
    ...
  end;
  if (Components[I] is TComboBox) then // Альтернативный вариант проверки
  begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Неизвестный идентификатор TComboBox!

Comment: в uses добавьте Vcl.StdCtrls

Comment: Очень *кудрявый* сниппет :-)